# How can I check if variable equal to other variable apart of (maybe) the last letter?

Tags: bash

Given the following variable:

```
var=abcd
```

What I need to write in the `if` so that I will get true if I will compare `var` with other variables so that they with beginning of `abcd` but maybe they with (at most) more a letter (in the last) ?

for example:

I want the following cases will give me TRUE:
`var` in related to `abcd`.
`var` in related to `abcde`.
`var` in related to `abcdk`.

And the following cases will give me FALSE:
`var` in related to `abc`.
`var` in related to `abcdee`.

Comment: They can end with any character, or exactly letter?

Comment: @randomir Like in my examples. to any character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pure POSIX, you can check if the variable itself is equal to `abcd`, or if the variable minus its last letter is equal.

```
if [ "$var" = abcd ] || [ "${var%?}" = abcd ]; then
```

Using `bash`'s `[[ ... ]]`, you can use either extended pattern matching

```
if [[ $var = abcd@(|?) ]]; then
```

(where `@(|?)` matches exactly one of the empty string or a single arbitrary character)

or a regular expression match

```
if [[ $var ~= ^abcd.?$ ]]; then
```

(where `.?` matches a single optional character. `^` and `$` match the beginning and end, respectively, of the string, limiting the length of the match).

Answer (score 2):

[The `[[` command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) in Bash does pattern matching on strings by default, so you can use `?`, `*` and [some other metacharacters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) for matching one (any, but exactly one) with `?`, zero or more characters with `*`, etc. For example:

```
$ [[ abcde == abcd? ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ abcdefg == abcd* ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ abc == abcd? ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
$ [[ abcd == abcd? ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Note that the value is on the left, and the pattern on the right. Also, `[[` supports the use of logical operators like `||` and `&&`, so you can combine it like:

```
ref=abcd
val=abcde
if [[ $val == $ref || $val == $ref? ]]; then
    # match
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional option using *string indexes* in bash. You can simply check whether the first `4` letters of a variable match `abcd` and check whether the variable length is greater than `5`, e.g.

```
if [[ abcd = ${var:0:4} ]] && [[ ${#var} -le 5 ]]; then
    ## condition true
fi
```

You have a number of options in bash. You can even make the testing above generic by storing your test string in a variable, and then using the *length* in place of each of the number above, e.g.

```
test_string="abcd"
len=${#test_string}

if [[ $test_string = ${var:0:$((len))} ]] && [[ ${#var} -le $((len+1)) ]]; then
    ## condition true
fi
```